# How can I explicitly NOT login to console session?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

A co-worker and I are both remotely logging into a server as the same administrative user.  Is there a way to force mstsc to NOT use the console session?  In other words, I'd like to login as the administrative user WITHOUT stealing my co-worker's console session.

Preemptive strike - I know it would be better to just use 2 accounts, but this is a legacy system, and the customer does not want to issue more administrative accounts (nor do they want to fudge w/ user account settings on our existing non-admin accounts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have ensure the RDP server is set to allow a user to have more than one session.

To do this, check group polices; specifically `Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Terminal Services > "Restrict Terminal Services users to a single remote session"`

Also ensure you're not using the `/admin` switch when launching the RDP client (MSTSC.exe).

Comment: Right, I know about the /admin switch; I'm definitely not using that.  I'll try the RDP Group Policy though.  Thanks!